# Optimizing Three.js for asingle large model

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am building a file browser / 3D model viewer. I want to load models of various formats (atm only .OBJ) into the scene and get a reasonable framerate with orbitControls.js.

Most optimization strategies I have seen are centered around dealing with many meshes not one single big mesh. 
The all time best goal would be to load huge files (hundreds of thousands / million vertices) and not have everything crash. I know that is far fetched, but I don't even know where to start with optimization for this problem so I can improve my framerate at least a little. Google hasn't helped me so far

Comment: Are you using `OBJLoader`? Also, what version of `THREE.js` are you using?

Comment: Yes and the newest version

Comment: The largest possible size for an index buffer is 65535 for webgl1. So it is rare to use a single mesh to present a model with enough detail. Recomposing the data in attribute buffers might be possible. But how it pushes the buffer size limit depends on which algorithm the models are created.

Comment: There is no limit in the index buffer size. if It's encoded as Short (16bit), indices values cannot exceed 65535, thus you cannot reference vertices beyond this limit. That said there is an extensions to encode indices in 32bits which is almost 100% supported in webgl1.

Answer (score 0):

One thing `OBJLoader` doesn't do--which could really help improve your performance--is indexing (faces with shared vertex/normal pairs). I exported a cube from Blender, and got 36 indices (1 triangle = 3 vertices, 2 triangles per cube face = 6 vertices, 6 faces = 36 total vertices). The same cube with indexing would be 24 vertices.

Indexing *does* increase the size of your object by the number of indices. The cube is a bad example of this (24 indices) because very few faces share the same vertex, but for complex meshes, the savings can be quite high.

I think explaining all the details of how indexing works is beyond the scope of an answer, and I'm sure other resources have done a better job than I could, but here's a small example of a plane:

```
var planeGeo = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
planeGeo.addAttribute("position", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([
    -10, 10, 0,
    -10, -10, 0,
    10, -10, 0,
    10, 10, 0
]), 3));
planeGeo.addAttribute("normal", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([
    0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 1
]), 3));
planeGeo.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([
    // triangle 1
    0, 1, 2,
    // triangle 2
    3, 2, 1
]), 1));
```

Notice that two of the vertex indices are used twice, allowing us to only have one copy of the vertex in the `position` buffer.

One thing to keep in mind though is that indices should work on vertex/normal pairs. Vertices and normals don't have discrete indexing, so if one vertex has two normals, you will still need a second copy of the vertex values in the `position` buffer.

But how does this help you? Well, it doesn't directly. What I'm suggesting is that you either modify `OBJLoader` to create indexed `BufferGeometry` objects (the `parse` method will need to be made smarter to create proper indexing), or write your own completely new `parse` function. The latter will actually be more useful to you, as you may need to create new loaders to handle the other file formats you wish to support.